# Parse Xml tags with attributes

Tags: parsing, groovy, xmlslurper

I have this xml :

```
<document-display>

                    <name>
                        <entry lang="nl">nl Text</entry>
                        <entry lang="fr">fr Text</entry>
                        <entry lang="en">en Text</entry>
                    </name>
</document-display>
```

I would like to get the text according to the langage.

I'm using XmlSlurper.

With my current code :

```
def parsedD = new XmlSlurper().parse(xml)
parsedD."document-display".name.entry.each {it.@lang == 'fr'}
```

I have as bad result which is the concatenation of the 3 text content :

```
nl Textfr Texten Text
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
parsedD.name.entry.find { it.@lang == 'fr' }?.text()
```